# Sendkeys to the right custom Excel ribbon

Tags: excel, vba, ribbon, sendkeys

I'm working with a custom Excel add-in that unfortunately doesn't expose its functions to VBA, so I'm resorting to a SendKeys approach ([see picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efyCI.png)). Excel assigns Y1 to the Help ribbon, and all the other custom add-ins get assigned Y2, Y3, etc.  Thankfully, it looks like these shortcut keys are consistent internationally (Japan, LatAm).

The issue is that depending on the installation order, custom ribbons will get assigned a different shortcut key for different users.

I'm looking for a way to identify the position of "DataFlow" ribbon in Excel so I can SendKeys to the right ribbon.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The Excel extensibility model doesn't provide anything for that. You can try using the [Microsoft Active Accessibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/microsoft-active-accessibility) technology to identify where tab controls are located and their properties.

The Fluent UI provides the [IRibboUI.ActivateTab](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.core.iribbonui.activatetab?view=office-pia) method which activates the specified custom tab. You just need to specify the identifier of the custom Ribbon tab to be activated.